# Servicenow Request body exceeded max allowed content length

Tags: visual-studio, app-config, servicenow

I'm using Visual Studio (C#)  in order to insert data into a table of Servicenow.
When I run the script I get the following error:
Request body exceeded max allowed content length.

I already tried changing values in app.config file, and there is not a file called web.config.

What can I do to solve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You didn't gave much details. Assuming you are trying to make REST API calls. Take a look at two properties (table `sys_properties`) in ServiceNow:

```
glide.rest.scripted.max_inbound_content_length_mb
glide.rest.scripted.max_inbound_gzip_content_length_mb
```

Second is for requests that are gzipped and first one not gzipped.